# JQuery match .val() as you type

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a form where you enter your first name. As you type in your name into the input field, a DIV above the form matches the value as you type.

```
$('#rendered').html($('#your_name').val());
```

The code above works on submit, but does not match letter by letter as you type?
Can someone point me in the right direction, should be pretty simple.

Comment: What event are you using? the above code would only work once.

Comment: Currently I'm not using an event. I need to set up a listener on #your_name? I'm a JQuery rookie and learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [**keyup**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```

JS:

```
$("#txt").on("keyup", function(e){
    $("#result").html($(this).val());
});
```

Here is the [<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/hc9T2/1/)

Comment: I've got to wait five more minutes, then I'm on it!

Comment: You can get a faster response time using `keydown` and a setTimeout, or `input` in more recent browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/hc9T2/3/